# How to get the largest and smallest elements in a 2 dimensional array in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a 2 dimensional array:

```
List<List<double>> intArr = [[467.0, 445.5], [480.0, 448.5],
                             [502.5, 450.5], [542.5, 449.5],
                             [575.0, 444.0], [610.5, 442.5],
                             [650.5, 447.5], [670.5, 451.5],
                             [700.5, 456.0], [723.5, 456.0],
                             [729.5, 456.0], [730.0, 456.0],
                             [730.0, 456.5]]
```

I want to get the biggest and smallest elements in this array. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<num>> intArr = [
    [467.0, 445.5],
    [480.0, 448.5],
    [502.5, 450.5],
    [542.5, 449.5],
    [575.0, 444.0],
    [610.5, 442.5],
    [650.5, 447.5],
    [670.5, 451.5],
    [700.5, 456.0],
    [723.5, 456.0],
    [729.5, 456.0],
    [730.0, 456.0],
    [730.0, 456.5]
  ];

  List biggestPair = intArr[0];
  List smallestPair = intArr[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
    List pair = intArr[i];
    if (pair[0] >= biggestPair[0]) {
      if (pair[1] < biggestPair[1]) {
        continue;
      }
      biggestPair = pair;
    } else if (pair[0] <= smallestPair[0]) {
      if (pair[1] > smallestPair[1]) {
        continue;
      }
      smallestPair = pair;
    }
  }
  List newArr = [biggestPair, smallestPair];
  print(newArr);
```

This prints the desired output

Comment: I wrote your code and ran it. It keeps popping up like below. flutter: [[564.5, 443.0], [568.0, 505.5], [564.5, 546.5], [558.5, 599.0], [557.0, 627.5], [558.5, 653.0], [559.5, 681.5], [559.5, 706.0] ]
flutter: [[559.5, 706.0], [0.0]]

Comment: @ahmetçıtır edited, should work now :)